# Select previous and next N rows with the same value as a certain row

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

I construct the following panel data with keys `id` and `time`:

```
pdata <- tibble(
  id = rep(1:10, each = 5),
  time = rep(2016:2020, times = 10),
  value = c(c(1,1,1,0,0), c(1,1,0,0,0), c(0,0,1,0,0), c(0,0,0,0,0), c(1,0,0,0,1), c(0,1,1,1,0), c(0,1,1,1,1), c(1,1,1,1,1), c(1,0,1,1,1), c(1,1,0,1,1))
)
pdata
# A tibble: 50 × 3
      id  time value
   <int> <int> <dbl>
 1     1  2016     1
 2     1  2017     1
 3     1  2018     1
 4     1  2019     0
 5     1  2020     0
 6     2  2016     1
 7     2  2017     1
 8     2  2018     0
 9     2  2019     0
10     2  2020     0
# … with 40 more rows
```

Let's assume a shock happened in 2018. I wish to slice pairs of previous and next N rows by `id` that have the same value as the shock rows' value.

I take several examples for illustration. For `id == 5`, the dataset looks like:

```
pdata %>% filter(id == 5)
# A tibble: 5 × 3
     id  time value
  <int> <int> <dbl>
1     5  2016     1
2     5  2017     0
3     5  2018     0
4     5  2019     0
5     5  2020     1
```

The `value` in 2018 for `id == 5` is 0, and I wish to keep the previous and next **1** row including the current row because all these observations have the same value that equals 0:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
     id  time value
  <int> <int> <dbl>
1     5  2017     0
2     5  2018     0
3     5  2019     0
```

For `id == 8`, I wish to get:

```
# A tibble: 5 × 3
     id  time value
  <int> <int> <dbl>
1     8  2016     1
2     8  2017     1
3     8  2018     1
4     8  2019     1
5     8  2020     1
```

For `id == 1`, I wish to get the empty dataset, since the pair of the observation in 2017 and the observation in 2019 does not have the same value.

The final dataset should be:

```
# A tibble: 19 × 3
      id  time value
   <int> <int> <dbl>
 1     4  2016     0
 2     4  2017     0
 3     4  2018     0
 4     4  2019     0
 5     4  2020     0
 6     5  2017     0
 7     5  2018     0
 8     5  2019     0
 9     6  2017     1
10     6  2018     1
11     6  2019     1
12     7  2017     1
13     7  2018     1
14     7  2019     1
15     8  2016     1
16     8  2017     1
17     8  2018     1
18     8  2019     1
19     8  2020     1
```

Comment: Have you seen [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70677147/select-previous-and-next-n-rows-with-the-same-value-as-a-certain-row/70679569#comment124949908_70679569) from @Henrik? Maybe you could clarify?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A solution with [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table):

```
# load the package & convert data to a data.table
library(data.table)
setDT(pdata)

# define shock-year and number of previous/next rows
shock <- 2018
n <- 2

# filter
pdata[, .SD[value == value[time == shock] &
              between(time, shock - n, shock + n) & 
              value == rev(value)][.N > 1 & all(diff(time) == 1)]
      , by = id]
```

which gives:

> ```
>     id time value
>  1:  4 2016     0
>  2:  4 2017     0
>  3:  4 2018     0
>  4:  4 2019     0
>  5:  4 2020     0
>  6:  5 2017     0
>  7:  5 2018     0
>  8:  5 2019     0
>  9:  6 2017     1
> 10:  6 2018     1
> 11:  6 2019     1
> 12:  7 2017     1
> 13:  7 2018     1
> 14:  7 2019     1
> 15:  8 2016     1
> 16:  8 2017     1
> 17:  8 2018     1
> 18:  8 2019     1
> 19:  8 2020     1
> ```

---

Used data:

```
pdata <- data.frame(
  id = rep(1:10, each = 5),
  time = rep(2016:2020, times = 10),
  value = c(c(1,1,1,0,0), c(1,1,0,0,0), c(0,0,1,0,0), c(0,0,0,0,0), c(1,0,0,0,1), c(0,1,1,1,0), c(0,1,1,1,1), c(1,1,1,1,1), c(1,0,1,1,1), c(1,1,0,1,1))
)
```

Comment: Hi @Jaap! I may have misunderstood the question (again)...but when reading "previous and next N rows by id that have the same value as the shock rows' value", I didn't think of N as fixed across group. I thought we should select the _maximum_ number of rows with equal values before and after the focal year. E.g. with `pdata = data.table(id = 1, time = 2015:2021, value = 0)` I would expect all rows to be selected, not "only" the (hardcoded) N rows. Perhaps OP care to clarify? Cheers

Comment: @Henrik I've posted a comment under the question with a link to your comment to get OP's attention. Hopefully OP can give some clarification.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just saw this comment. Thanks for the excellent answer provided. I am very inspired. @Henrik is right. N is flexible and not fixed across groups.

Answer (score 4):

##### Symmetrical range around focal year & range may differ among 'id'

Within each 'id' (`by = id`), use `rleid` to create a grouping variable 'r' based on runs of equal values. Within each 'id' and run (`by = .(id, r)`), check if at least previous and next year from the focal year (e.g. 2018) are present (`if(sum(time %in% yr_rng) == 3)`). If so, select equal number of rows before and after the focal year (`min(c(shock - .I[1], .I[.N] - shock)`). Note that here the number of years selected may vary among 'id'.

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(pdata)
yr = 2018
yr_rng = (yr - 1):(yr + 1)

pdata[ , r := rleid(value), by = id]
pdata[pdata[ , if(sum(time %in% yr_rng) == 3) {
  shock = .I[time == 2018]
  rng = min(c(shock - .I[1], .I[.N] - shock))
  (shock - rng):(shock + rng)
}, by = .(id, r)]$V1] 

    id time value r
 1:  4 2016     0 1
 2:  4 2017     0 1
 3:  4 2018     0 1
 4:  4 2019     0 1
 5:  4 2020     0 1
 6:  5 2017     0 2
 7:  5 2018     0 2
 8:  5 2019     0 2
 9:  6 2017     1 2
10:  6 2018     1 2
11:  6 2019     1 2
12:  7 2017     1 2
13:  7 2018     1 2
14:  7 2019     1 2
15:  8 2016     1 1
16:  8 2017     1 1
17:  8 2018     1 1
18:  8 2019     1 1
19:  8 2020     1 1
```

---

##### Allowing asymmetrical range around focal year

Within each 'id' and run (`by = .(id, r)`), check if both previous and next year from the focal year (e.g. 2018) are present (`if(sum(time %in% yr_rng) == 3)`). If so, select the entire group (`.SD`).

```r
pdata[ , r := rleid(value), by = id]
pdata[ , if(sum(time %in% yr_rng) == 3) .SD, by = .(id, r)]

    id r time value
 1:  4 1 2016     0
 2:  4 1 2017     0
 3:  4 1 2018     0
 4:  4 1 2019     0
 5:  4 1 2020     0
 6:  5 2 2017     0
 7:  5 2 2018     0
 8:  5 2 2019     0
 9:  6 2 2017     1
10:  6 2 2018     1
11:  6 2 2019     1
12:  7 2 2017     1
13:  7 2 2018     1
14:  7 2 2019     1
15:  7 2 2020     1
16:  8 1 2016     1
17:  8 1 2017     1
18:  8 1 2018     1
19:  8 1 2019     1
20:  8 1 2020     1
```

Comment: Nice @Henrik, only thing to change is the last row reduction keeps years like `2020` in `id == 7`, where I think the desired behavior is only keeping a symmetrical number of rows around the target year. I originally had basically your same solution but in `dplyr`, and most streamlined I could find was my answer below. You might find something sleeker!

Comment: @caldwellst Ooops, thanks. Seems like I misread the question. I certainly didn't think about the equal number of years / symmetry, around the target year... I'll see if I find some time to edit. Cheers

Comment: @jaap has a great solution.

Comment: @jaap _always_ has great solutions ;)

Comment: @Henrik thx & I would say the same about you ;-)

Comment: @caldwellst I added code for symmetrical ranges. Also please note that my answers allow for _different_ range sizes among groups (see [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70677147/select-previous-and-next-n-rows-based-on-the-condition-for-current-row/70679511?noredirect=1#comment124949908_70679569) asking OP for clarification.)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood, here's a `dplyr` suggestion:

```
library(dplyr)

MyF <- function(id2, shock, nb_row) {
  values <- pdata %>%
    filter(id == id2) %>%
    pull(value)
  
  if (length(unique(values)) == 1) {
    pdata %>%
      filter(id == id2)
  } else {
    pdata %>%
      filter(id == id2) %>%
      filter(time >= shock - nb_row & time <= shock + nb_row) %>%
      filter(length(unique(value)) == 1)
  }
  
  
}

map_df(pdata %>%
         select(id) %>% 
         distinct() %>% 
         pull(),
       MyF,
       shock = 2018, nb_row = 1)

## Or map_df(1:8,MyF,shock = 2018, nb_row = 1)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 19 x 3
      id  time value
   <int> <int> <dbl>
 1     4  2016     0
 2     4  2017     0
 3     4  2018     0
 4     4  2019     0
 5     4  2020     0
 6     5  2017     0
 7     5  2018     0
 8     5  2019     0
 9     6  2017     1
10     6  2018     1
11     6  2019     1
12     7  2017     1
13     7  2018     1
14     7  2019     1
15     8  2016     1
16     8  2017     1
17     8  2018     1
18     8  2019     1
19     8  2020     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another `dplyr` solution. We basically group by sequences of unique values for each `id` and then just filter around the maximum distance to the shock time that is duplicated.

```r
pdata %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(value_group = cumsum(value != lag(value, default = value[1]))) %>%
  group_by(id, value_group) %>%
  mutate(shock_diff = abs(time - 2018)) %>%
  filter(shock_diff <= max(shock_diff[duplicated(shock_diff)], -Inf))
#> # A tibble: 19 × 5
#> # Groups:   id, value_group [5]
#>       id  time value value_group shock_diff
#>    <int> <int> <dbl>       <int>      <dbl>
#>  1     4  2016     0           0          2
#>  2     4  2017     0           0          1
#>  3     4  2018     0           0          0
#>  4     4  2019     0           0          1
#>  5     4  2020     0           0          2
#>  6     5  2017     0           1          1
#>  7     5  2018     0           1          0
#>  8     5  2019     0           1          1
#>  9     6  2017     1           1          1
#> 10     6  2018     1           1          0
#> 11     6  2019     1           1          1
#> 12     7  2017     1           1          1
#> 13     7  2018     1           1          0
#> 14     7  2019     1           1          1
#> 15     8  2016     1           0          2
#> 16     8  2017     1           0          1
#> 17     8  2018     1           0          0
#> 18     8  2019     1           0          1
#> 19     8  2020     1           0          2
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve your problem using data.table:

```
library(data.table)

yrs=2017:2019
setDT(pdata)[, if(uniqueN(value)==1) .(time, value) 
               else if(uniqueN(value <- value[time %in% yrs])==1) .(time=yrs, value), 
             by=id]

#        id  time value
#  1:     4  2016     0
#  2:     4  2017     0
#  3:     4  2018     0
#  4:     4  2019     0
#  5:     4  2020     0
#  6:     5  2017     0
#  7:     5  2018     0
#  8:     5  2019     0
#  9:     6  2017     1
# 10:     6  2018     1
# 11:     6  2019     1
# 12:     7  2017     1
# 13:     7  2018     1
# 14:     7  2019     1
# 15:     8  2016     1
# 16:     8  2017     1
# 17:     8  2018     1
# 18:     8  2019     1
# 19:     8  2020     1
```

Comment: Hi @B. Christian Kamgang! I _think_ the `if(uniqueN(value)==1) .(time, value)` may fail to handle the "symmetry aspect" of the question. Imagine all values are equal with an id, with two rows before 2018 and three rows after 2018. AFAIU we then should select the 2 before and also two after, not all rows after. I hope I haven't messed thing up...Cheers